# No clamp or repeat on texture2DProj

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

Is there a way of telling `texture2DProj` or set the texture in a mode in which a default value would be displayed if the coordinates are outside of the boundaries? One way would be to set the borders of the image to the default value and use clamping. Any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to test if the coordinates are within range in the shader, and assign the default value otherwise.

If your call is normally:

```
vec3 texCoord = ...;
vec4 texVal = texture2DProj(tex, texCoord);
```

You could change it to:

```
vec4 texVal;
if (any(bvec4(texCoord[0] < 0.0, texCoord[1] < 0.0,
              texCoord[0] > texCoord[2], texCoord[1] > texCoord[2]))) {
    texVal = defaultVal;
} else {
    texVal = texture2DProj(tex, texCoord);
}
```